# Find whether a tree is a binary search tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, predicate

```
  type BSTree a = BinaryTree a

  data BinaryTree a = Null | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
                      deriving Show

  flattenTree :: BinaryTree a -> [a]
  flattenTree  tree = case tree of
      Null -> []
      Node left val right -> (flattenTree left) ++ [val] ++ (flattenTree right)

  isBSTree :: (Ord a) => BinaryTree a -> Bool
  isBSTree btree = case btree of
      Null -> False
      tree -> (flattenTree tree) == sort (flattenTree tree)
```

What I want to do is to write a function to determine whether the given tree is a binary search tree, my method is to group all of the values in a list and import `Data.List` and then sort the list to find whether they are equal, but it is a little complicated. Can we do this without importing other module?

Comment: I wouldn't define `flattenTree` first. You can return `False` early if a node violates the search property without having to traverse the entire subtree rooted at that node.

Comment: @chepner the problem is with `sort`, not with `flattenTree`, which is lazy enough.

Comment: Yeah, that occurred to me after looking at some of the other answers.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a way to do it without flattening the tree.

From the definition, here,

```
data BinaryTree a = Null | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
     deriving Show
```

one can see that traversing the tree left to right, ignoring `Node` and parentheses, gives you an alternating sequence of `Null`s and `a`s. That is, between every two values, there is a `Null`.

My plan is to check that each subtree satisfies suitable *requirements*: we can *refine* the requirements at each `Node`, remembering which values we are between, then *test* them at each `Null`. As there is a `Null` between every in order pair of values, we will have tested that all in order (left-to-right) pairs are non-decreasing.

What is a requirement? It's a *loose* lower and upper bound on the values in the tree. To express requirements, including those at the leftmost and rightmost ends, we may extend any ordering with `Bot`tom and `Top` elements, as follows:

```
data TopBot a = Bot | Val a | Top deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Now let us check that a given tree satisfies the requirements of being both in order and between given bounds.

```
ordBetween :: Ord a => TopBot a -> TopBot a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool
  -- tighten the demanded bounds, left and right of any Node
ordBetween lo hi (Node l x r) = ordBetween lo (Val x) l && ordBetween (Val x) hi r
  -- check that the demanded bounds are in order when we reach Null
ordBetween lo hi Null         = lo <= hi
```

A binary search tree is a tree that is in order and between `Bot` and `Top`.

```
isBSTree :: Ord a => BinaryTree a -> Bool
isBSTree = ordBetween Bot Top
```

Computing the *actual* extremal values in each subtree, bubbling them outwards, gives you more information than you need, and is fiddly in the edge cases where a left or right subtree is empty. Maintaining and checking the *requirements*, pushing them inwards, is rather more uniform.

Comment: (just a suggestion,) you could flag this answer (or any other) and ask moderators to merge your older account https://stackoverflow.com/users/733183/conor into this one, so people could see those two other answers from there as well. (I tried asking the mods to do this, but they said only the user themself could request the merging of accounts). :) (hope me pinging you here is not too much of a bother)

Comment: Why wait until Null to compare bounds? It seems more natural to me to, at each Node, check that the value is within the already-established bounds before recursing. This tweak should be lazier: it can correctly produce `False` for the tree `Node (Node undefined 10 undefined) 5 Null`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a hint: make an auxiliary function

```
isBSTree' :: (Ord a) => BinaryTree a -> BSTResult a
```

where `BSTResult a` is defined as

```
data BSTResult a
   = NotBST             -- not a BST
   | EmptyBST           -- empty tree (hence a BST)
   | NonEmptyBST a a    -- nonempty BST with provided minimum and maximum
```

You should be able to proceed recursively, exploiting results on subtrees to drive the computation, in particular the minimum and maximum.

For instance, if you have `tree = Node left 20 right`, with `isBSTree' left = NonEmptyBST 1 14` and `isBSTree' right = NonEmptyBST 21 45`, then `isBSTree' tree` should be `NonEmptyBST 1 45`.

In the same case except for `tree = Node left 24 right`, we should instead have `isBSTree' tree = NotBST`.

Converting the result to `Bool` is then trivial.

Comment: or define the obvious Monoid for `BSTResult a` and fold into it. :) (or even if it's not a lawful Monoid ....)

Comment: (but it is lawful, anyway, I think)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you do not need to sort the list. You can check if every element is less than or equal to the next element. This is more efficient since we can do this in *O(n)*, whereas evaluating the sorted list *completely* takes *O(n* log *n)*.

We thus can check this with:

```
ordered :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
ordered [] = True
ordered xa@(_:xs) = and (zipWith (<=) xa xs)
```

So we can check if the binary tree is a binary search tree with:

```
isBSTree :: Ord a => BinaryTree a -> Bool
isBSTree = ordered . flattenTree
```

I think one can claim that `Null` itself is a binary search tree, since it is an empty tree. This thus means that for every node (there are no nodes) the elements in the left subtree are less than or equal to the value in the node, and the elements in the right subtree are all greater than or equal to the value in the node.

Answer (score 1):

We can proceed left-to-right over the tree like this:

```
isBSTtreeG :: Ord a => BinaryTree a -> Bool
isBSTtreeG t = gopher Nothing [Right t]
    where
    gopher  _   []                        =  True
    gopher  x   (Right Null:ts)           =  gopher x ts
    gopher  x   (Right (Node lt v rt):ts) =  gopher x (Right lt:Left v:Right rt:ts)
    gopher Nothing   (Left v:ts)          =  gopher (Just v) ts
    gopher (Just y)  (Left v:ts)          =  y <= v && gopher (Just v) ts
```

Inspired by [John McCarthy's `gopher`](https://dreamsongs.com/10ideas.html).

The explicit push-down list can be eliminated with continuation-passing,

```
isBSTtreeC :: Ord a => BinaryTree a -> Bool
isBSTtreeC t = gopher Nothing t (const True)
    where
    gopher  x   Null           g  =  g x 
    gopher  x   (Node lt v rt) g  =  gopher x lt (\case
                                       Nothing -> gopher (Just v) rt g
                                       Just y  -> y <= v && gopher (Just v) rt g)
```

Maintaining just one, *largest-so-far* element, is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I try to do this [check binary search tree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TC9YPLyTTDo&t=1051s) implementation closer to BST definition "for every node X the all left subtree nodes < X and all right subtree nodes >= X":

```
data Btree a = Empty | Node a (Btree a) (Btree a) deriving Show

instance Functor Btree where
  fmap _ Empty = Empty
  fmap f (Node v l r) = Node (f v) (fmap f l) (fmap f r)

instance Foldable Btree where
  --  foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
  foldMap _ Empty = mempty
  foldMap f (Node v l r) = (f v) <> foldMap f l <> foldMap f r

check :: Ord a => Btree a -> Bool
check Empty = True
check (Node v l r) = all' (v>) l && all' (v<=) r && check l && check r
                     where all' f b = foldr (&&) True $ f <$> b
```