# Binary search tree predicate with helper functions

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, predicate

```
data BinaryTree a = Null | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
deriving Show

type BSTree a = BinaryTree a

treeBSMax :: (Ord a) => BSTree a -> a
treeBSMax   btree = case btree of
        Null -> error
        Node _ val Null -> val
        Node _ val right -> treeBSMax right

treeBSMin :: (Ord a) => BSTree a -> a
treeBSMin btree = case btree of
       Null -> error
       Node Null val _ -> val
       Node left val _ -> treeBSMax left

isBSTree :: (Ord a) => BinaryTree a -> Bool
isBSTree btree = case btree of
      Null -> False
      Node Null val Null -> True
      Node lt val rt -> val >  treeBSMin lt && val < treeBSMax rt
```

How can I use `treeBSMin` and `treeBSMax` as helper functions of `isBSTree` to find whether a tree is a binary search tree?

Comment: Why do you need `treeBSMin` and `treeBSMax` in order to know if it is a binary tree? You can recursively work, with first unset bounds that are set each time you move further into the tree.

Comment: The question is I don't know how to recursively compare elements in the tree.

Comment: you just use parameters in the recursive call, like demonstrated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58305672/67579

Comment: Note that in `isBSTree` you consider the cases where both subtrees are empty, and where both subtrees are nonempty. This does not cover all cases, and will result in an error from the minimum/maximum helper functions.

Comment: @chi a. "where both subtrees are nonempty" I don't see it. b. the error is much worse than that.

Comment: @WillNess a. `treeBSMin, treeBSMax`, as written, require non empty trees -- indeed, you wrote below that they are partial. Hence, we must be sure to call then when they are defined (or, better, change them as you did). b. that's true.

Comment: @chi that goes to operational correctness, but the case handling is via pattern matching,  in `isBSTree`. so, the `error` is just an error to be fixed, but the code structure is good, was my thinking.

Answer (score 1):

To use them as helper functions you need to first remove *partiality* from your code by using `Maybe`:

```
treeBSMax :: (Ord a) => BSTree a -> Maybe a
treeBSMax   btree = case btree of
        Null -> Nothing
        Node _ val Null -> Just val
        Node _ val right -> treeBSMax right

treeBSMin :: (Ord a) => BSTree a -> Maybe a
treeBSMin btree = case btree of
       Null -> Nothing
       Node Null val _ -> Just val
       Node left val _ -> treeBSMin left

isBSTree :: (Ord a) => BinaryTree a -> Bool
isBSTree btree = case btree of
      Null -> True                       -- changed it!
      Node Null val Null -> True
      Node lt val rt -> isBSTree lt       -- these two lines
                        && isBSTree rt     -- were missing !!
                        && inOrder (treeBSMax lt) val (treeBSMin rt)
                 where
                 inOrder Nothing  _ Nothing   =  True
                 inOrder Nothing  v (Just y)  =  v <= y
                 inOrder (Just x) v Nothing   =  x <= v
                 inOrder (Just x) v (Just y)  =  x <= v && v <= y
```

This is not efficient of course. (*why* is left as an exercise)

Comment: Is `Node Null val Null -> True` needed?

Comment: *correctness first, efficiency later!* and it might actually improve efficiency even if it's redundant. besides, the algorithm itself is abysmally inefficient anyway.