# Haskell max from parameterized binary search tree

Tags: haskell

I have this function to get min value from my BST, type Int:

```
maxBST    :: BST Int -> Int
maxBST    Nil  = -1000000
maxBST    (Node left value right)  = max (maxBST left) (max value (maxBST right))
```

Now I want to remake this function so that it also works for parameterized BST, like this:

```
maxBST       :: (Ord t) => BST t -> t
maxBST Nil   =  //?
maxBST (Node left value right) = max (maxBST left) (max value (maxBST right))
```

The problem here is to find the correct //? value, so that it's minimum for type `t`. Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: It doesn't affect the answer to your question, but, if this is really a binary search tree you shouldn't need to walk the whole thing to find where the maximum element is.

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental problem here is that your type signature (like that of `maximum`) is a lie. You cannot guarantee to produce the maximal element from a data structure that may contain no elements. A special sentinel value can paper over this issue in some cases, but even in those cases it breaks down if you look carefully. What is the minimum element of `Node Nil -2000000 Nil`? This is a nonempty tree, so you should be able to get its maximum, but your implementation returns -1000000 instead, as though the tree were empty!

One thing you could try that would do a better job of sweeping the problem under the rug would be to add a Bounded constraint, so that you could use `minBound` as the "neutral" element. Then at least you don't get erroneous results as in my example, but you still can't tell an empty tree from a tree containing only the minimum.

Better is to adjust your type signature to tell the truth. You can return `Maybe t` instead of just `t`, using Nothing to indicate "sorry, this tree was empty". As for implementation, you can just the the obvious brute-force thing of pattern-matching on the recursive calls - it's clunky, but it works.

Better still, though, would be to implement Foldable for your tree type (a good idea in any case), so that you can take advantage of its `toList`. Presuming that you have done so, this maximum function becomes easy:

```
maxBST t = case toList t of
  [] -> Nothing
  xs -> Just $ maximum xs
```

Comment: user:pigworker has a nice answer on this problem, with foldMap over an extended type IIRC. I'll try to find the link... [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58305672/849891) - although it's a different, though related, problem.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @amalloy's answer, that returning a `Maybe` type is the best approach here.

However, there is another approach if you are determined to always return an "actual value" and have it be a sensible "minimum" for the type. And that is to alter the type signature so that the elements of the tree must be of a type that is an instance of [Bounded](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) as well as `Ord`. This would be:

```
maxBST       :: (Ord t, Bounded t) => BST t -> t
maxBST Nil   =  minBound
maxBST (Node left value right) = max (maxBST left) (max value (maxBST right))
```

Note that, although this will work on `Int`, it won't be identical to your original function, because the `minBound` for `Int` is much less than -1000000.

Comment: I did mention this option in my answer, and you're missing the important caveat I included: it's impossible to tell the difference between an empty tree and a tree containing only the `minBound` value.

Answer (score 1):

Don't goto nil, just destructure left and right and see if both of them are nil and handle the cases

```
maxBST Nil = error "your function shouldn't reach here"
maxBST (Node Nil value Nil) = value
maxBST (Node left@(Node _ _ _) value Nil) = max (maxBST left) value
maxBST (Node Nil value right@(Node _ _ _)) = max value (maxBST right)
```